# SQL Server 2008 Sharepoint list

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint

I am trying to link a `sharepoint` list to another using `sql server database`. The ideal would be for this is to a live link so that when data in the sharepoint list is updated, the data in the sql server database is also updated. The reason that I need to do this is that I have an ASP page which will query the SQL database and display the results on a web page.

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

SidJ

> PS : I have done this in access before using the External Data tab ->
>   More -> Sharepoint List and then following the steps in the wizard, so
>   I know it is possible. Just not sure how to recreate this using SQL
>   Server as the destination for the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can go BCS (Business Connectivity Services) or build something custom using a connector like http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/

Here is a small guide on BCS http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-programmatically-work-with-external-lists-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010